# SQL Server 2005 bulk insert with format file error

Tags: sql-server-2005, csv, bulkinsert

error list

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 7, Line 2
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. 
>   Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. 
>   The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

fmt file

```
9.0
10
1       SQLCHAR       2       50      ","   2     EmployeeSSN       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                    
2       SQLCHAR       2       50      ","   3     DOB               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                       
3       SQLCHAR       2       50      ","   4     Gender            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                       
4       SQLCHAR       2       50      ","   5     Relcode           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                          
5       SQLCHAR       2       50      ","   6     EmployeeID           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                      
6       SQLCHAR       2       50      ","   7     AssessmentType       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                    
7       SQLCHAR       2       50      ","   8     MeasurementDate      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                       
8       SQLCHAR       2       50      ","   9     RecordCreationDate   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                    
9       SQLCHAR       2       50      ","   10    AttributeID       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                              
10      SQLCHAR       2       50      "/r/n"   11   AttributeValue    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Bulk insert code

```
BULK insert *******_raw_data
from 'E:\*****_csv\BWC_To_*****_2.csv'
with (formatfile = 'c:\*******_raw_data-n.fmt');
```

first line from csv

```
NULL,07/14/1983,F,S,105***,HRA,09/28/2011,09/28/2011,19,1
```

I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong here.... I have gotten other files to work but have been unsuccessful with this one. The files' names are correct in my code they are starred out because they are company names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error: 
Msg 4866, Level 16, State 7, Line 2
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

This is either a problem with NULL or the row terminator. 
The last terminator for the row may not be "/r/n", it could be "/n". It is best to confirm that with a Hex Editor.

Second and Third Error: 
These all look like a NULL problem.

The correct way to handle nulls in BULK INSERT is to specify the KEEPNULLS option.

```
with (formatfile = 'c:\*******_raw_data-n.fmt',KEEPNULLS);
```

Create the csv files with an empty field for NULL values.

```
,07/14/1983,F,S,105***,HRA,09/28/2011,09/28/2011,19,1
```